# xcopy is not working invalid parameters

Tags: command-line

I have a bat file who is showing invalid number of parameters

Kindly check the code below

```
xcopy "\\IP\Scream Update\*" C:\Scream Update\* /K /D /H /S /Y
```

Any Ideas? Thank you

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? What OS and version is this running on? What is the specific error you are receiving? Use the EDIT button to add any and all relevant and helpful information to the question itself, to make the question better.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already the solution but for completeness: you should use quotation marks also for the second path argument. Another issue is that you have an asterisk at the end of the second argument

This should work fine:

```
xcopy "\\IP\Scream Update\*" "C:\Scream Update\" /K /D /H /S /Y
```